# How can I properly return a token within another call?

Tags: java, iterator, token

I am having a hard time getting the correct tokens within a string. I can only take tokens such as (false,true,or,and,not,),()). If a token in a string is "(false", then I need to return both "(" and "false". This is where I am having problems.

For example, my desired output is:

```
line: [ not (false or error true) ]
next token: [not]
next token: [(]
next token: [false]
next token: [or]
next token: [true]
next token: [)]
```

But my output is:

```
line: [ not (false or error true) ]
next token: [not]
next token: [(]
next token: [or]
next token: [true]
next token: [)]
```

While iterating to scan the next token of "or", I have already previously returned "(" and my next token is "false", but I cannot figure out how to return this. It skips it and returns "or".

Here are my methods.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    if(!scan.hasNext()){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public String next() {
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        scan.useDelimiter(" ");
        otherToken = scan.next();

    if(otherToken.contains("(") || otherToken.contains(")")){
        if(otherToken.contains("(")){
            nextToken = otherToken.substring(1, otherToken.length());
            return "(";
        }
        if(otherToken.contains(")")){
            nextToken = ")";
            return otherToken.substring(0, otherToken.length()-1);
        }
    }
    if(otherToken.equals("true") || otherToken.equals("false") || 
            otherToken.equals("or") || otherToken.equals("and") || 
            otherToken.equals("not")){
        nextToken = otherToken;
        return nextToken;
    }
    if(otherToken.equals("(") || otherToken.equals(")")){
        nextToken = otherToken;
        return nextToken;
    }
    else{
        continue;
    }
}
return nextToken;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want "error" as a token? If it was a token, not only would a solution be simple, but you would have context of where the "error" fit in your tokens - how were you going to find where the "error" token came from anyway??

Comment: error is not a valid token for my program, so I ignore it

Comment: so, can there be arbitrary "junk" between the tokens you want?

Comment: yes, i only need the valid ones which i listed above in my question

Answer (score 1):

With a little tweaking of the delimiter regex pattern, you can get the java Scanner to return the tokens you want:

```
    String line =" not (false or error true) ";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
    scan.useDelimiter(
            "(?<=(?:\\b(?:false|true|or|and|not)\\b)|[()]|^)" // lookbehind
            +".*?" // non-greedy match all
            +"(?=(?:\\b(?:false|true|or|and|not)\\b)|[()]|$)"); // lookahead
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        System.out.format("next token: [%s]%n", scan.next());
    }
```

**Output:**

> next token: [not]
>
> next token: [(]
>
> next token: [false]
>
> next token: [or]
>
> next token: [true]
>
> next token: [)]

However, it would be much simpler to just use a regex to find the tokens themselves:

```
    String line = "not (false or error true)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\b(?:false|true|or|and|not)\\b)|[()]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.format("next token: [%s]%n", m.group());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using space as a delimiter.  Here is a list of tokens created for your string "not (false or error true)"

1. not
2. (false
3. or
4. error
5. true)

The second token is "(false".  The following code returns "(" if a string containing a "(" is encountered:

```
if(otherToken.contains("(") || otherToken.contains(")")){ // STRING (false CONTAINS (
    if(otherToken.contains("(")){ // IF STRING CONTAINS ( WHICH (FALSE DOES
        nextToken = otherToken.substring(1, otherToken.length()); // NOT SURE WHERE nextToken IS USED.
        return "(";  // RETURN "("
    }
    if(otherToken.contains(")")){  // EVEN IF TOKEN IS 
        nextToken = ")";
        return otherToken.substring(0, otherToken.length()-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind tokenizing, there's a 1-line solution with `split()`:

```
String[] tokens = input.replaceAll("^.*?(?=[()]|\\b(or|not|true|false)\\b)|((?![()]|\\b(or|not|true|false)\\b).)*$", "")
.split("((?<=[()])|(?<=\\bor\\b)|(?<=\\bnot\\b)|(?<=\\btrue\\b)|(?<=\\bfalse\\b)).*?((?=[()]|\\b(or|not|true|false)\\b|$))");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/p04ebq).

This first trims off any leading or trailing junk, then uses look arounds to match *between* the target tokens.

Although somewhat of a regex train wreck, this caters for arbitrary "other characters", provided words are separated by spaces, and plucks out only the target tokens. For example, it would work on input such as `"xxx not yyy(zzz false aaa or bbb true ccc)ddd"`.

Comment: @PatrickParker no, only variable length look behinds cause problems. But the regex doesn't quite work anyway. I'm testing it until bit works and I'll post a working version when I have it (currently it's splitting out blanks too)

Comment: error is not a valid token, so I ignore it. Error is just a token within a string, not an actual "error"

Comment: @Bohemian sorry it's still not working. you are matching the "or" inside "error". check my answer.

Comment: @patrick lol I didn't notice that. I've added word boundaries... and the demo *actually* works now.